# Is this an accidental interference pattern?

Tags: visible-light, laser, interference, diffraction, home-experiment

I recently purchased this [laser level](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VRZS44Z). When I turned it on, I got excited when I noticed that it projected this interesting pattern on the wall:
[image: 'interference' pattern]
Is this an interference pattern? I don't know much about how laser levels work, but the pattern seems to match what I've seen in pictures online. Is it possible that the laser level is inadvertently creating one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a sort of interference pattern called a diffraction pattern. Most likely it is caused by the aperture of your laser level.